# Tests of Bazel: is there any tests for CppCompileAction.java?

Tags: unit-testing, bazel

I have been studying and using Bazel for a while in my work. For some reason, I have done some development on src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CppCompileAction.java. After that, I plan to add a couple of tests for the new changes. That's when I realize that, in the corresponding package (src/test/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/), there is no execution of any action. I was expecting something like the following

```
CppCompileAction action = ... CppCompileActionBuilder.build(...);
ActionResult result = action.execute(someActionExecutionContext);
```

Is there any reason? Is there any advice if I want to create a test like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bazel's java tests don't actually execute actions -- they simulate a build and verify the contents of registered actions, but don't actually execute these actions.

One reason for this is that, if a java test executed C++ compile actions, the test suite would depend on C++ tooling.

As an alternative, we have various shell (.sh) test suites which test Bazel end-to-end, including action execution.

[Here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/test/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CcCommonTest.java) is an example for a java test suite verifying compile actions.

.. and [Here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/test/shell/bazel/bazel_rules_test.sh) is an example of a shell test which fully tests a C++ build, *with* executing actions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Chris, I hit into another question about Bazel (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031883/how-options-from-copts-list-in-cc-library-are-populated-in-user-compile-fla)...It would be great if you can take a look when you have a second. Thanks!!